# JDBC type 4 connectivity using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I wrote a program to connect to a database using jdbc with type 4 connectivity. The program compiles just fine but gives an exception of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. I have extracted all the folders in the folder in which my java file is and even placed all the jar files and database in the same folder. The database contains two records with ID 1 and 2. What could be the problem?

```
import java.sql.*;

class TestJDBC {

public static void main(String aa[]) {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Student_Details", "root","");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select ID, studentname from Details where ID=1");

        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString("ID"));
            System.out.print("\t");
            System.out.println(rs.getString("StudentName"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` file is located with a path like `\lib\` within your Project like below

[image]

Then with a cmd prompt (assuming windows) change directory to this folder, then you would need to compile your class with

```
javac -cp ".;lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" YourClass.java
```

use `:` if not windows (only need quotes if spaces in file/folder names)

then run with

```
java -cp ".;lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" YourClass
```

Also make sure you dont have duplicate jars in use

Answer (score 1):

you need to have the jar containing `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in the class path

eg

`java -cp mysql.jar;. TestJDBC`

where mysql.jar is the jar containing the class file

`com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.class`

on a windows machine

placed `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` and `TestJDBC.class` in same folder.

from the folder executed 
`java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;. TestJDBC`

that worked as expected.

unix usually requires

`java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar:. TestJDBC`

Comment: Tried it but still getting the same exception

Comment: windows or linux or other?

Answer (score 0):

As answered by BevynQ, setting class path from command line sets the path(As best of my knowledge) for that particular current instance of cmd, if you exit/close and reopen command prompt, again you need to set the path.
I guess two solutions for this to use jar files in your programs:

- **Solution 1)** Copy jar files in Program Files/Java/JRE/lib folder, so that it will be available for run time environment, But this is not recommended to add jar files in JDK/JRE.
- **Solution 2)** Set the classpath variable to place the full path of your jar file location, So that it will be available for run time environment:
  Copy full path of your jar file location, go to environment variable, search for user/system classpath variable(User variable for current login user, system variable for all users accounts on current windows) if it is there, edit it and put your path in starting, otherwise create a new classpath variable and place your full path

[Look here to set class-path-](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: You should never put jar files in your JDK to get your classpath working. It is for JDK libs only (and some extension libraries). Also the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is almost never used by 'real' Java programs. You should - in general - ignore its existence.

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel: Thank you for nice suggestion. But as best of my knowledge by setting the classpath we inform to java run time environment-where to look for a particular API related jar files to locate the classes and other resources of that API. Please let me know if I am misleading.

Comment: Yes, that is what the classpath is for, but in general the environment variable `CLASSPATH` isn't used to define the classpath of an application (eg when you execute with `java -cp ...` or `java -jar ...`, Java Webstart etc, the `CLASSPATH` is ignored)